# CSS is breaking or not working in Mozilla and IE but working fine in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

Hi I made a **PHP table in HTML and CSS,  [layout](http://www.die-malireise.de/alle-reisen-weltweit8.php) is working fine in chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox and Internet explorer**, Whats should I do for compatibility or how should I debug for all the browsers? Also in I have tested on other machines with differenet version of browser and it works well. How will I rectify it and make it compatible for all browsers

chrome layout
[image: chrome layout]

Mozilla Firefox
[image: Mozilla Firefox]

IE
[image: IE]

CSS:

```
        <table class="termine">
                <?php
                // echo $newkeyjahrval." - ".$keyjahr."<br>";
                    if(strtolower($newkeyjahrval) != strtolower($keyjahr)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <div class="date" style="color:#fc453e">
                        <!-- <b><?php // echo $keyregion;  ?>&nbsp; <?php //echo $jahr;?></b><br> -->
                        <b><?php  echo $zeile[$i]->keyjahr; $keyjahrval++;?></b><br>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <?php }
                    if(strtolower($newkey_regionprint) != strtolower($key_regionprint)){
                 ?>
                <tr>
                    <b><caption class="date1"><?php echo $zeile[$i]->key_region; ?> </caption></b>
                </tr>
                <!-- <thead> -->
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="reisenr">Reise Nr.</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="land">Land</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="reise">Reise</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="datum">Reisedatum</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="dauer">Dauer</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="preis">Reisepreis</th>

                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <!-- </thead> -->
            <!-- <tbody> -->
                <?php
                    $anfang = htmlentities($zeile[$i]->beginn_f,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0);
                    $ende   = htmlentities($zeile[$i]->ende_f  ,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0);
                    $commen = ($zeile[$i]->comment_de) ? "<div class=\"comment\">". nl2br(htmlentities($zeile[$i]->comment_de,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0)) ."</div>" : "";
                    echo '<tr class="trails">';
                    echo '<td>'.$zeile[$i]->reisenr.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$zeile[$i]->keycountry.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$zeile[$i]->tourname.'</td>';
                    echo '<td class="commdate">'.$anfang.' &ndash; '.$ende.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.($zeile[$i]->tage+1).'&nbsp;T</td>';

                    if($zeile[$i]->price){
                        echo '<td>'.$zeile[$i]->price.'&nbsp;Euro</td>';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<td>-</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                    // $l=$i+1;
                    // while((count($zeile) - 1 > $i) && (count($zeile) - 1 > $l) && ($l > $i) && ($key_regionprint == $zeile[$l]->key_region)){
                        $k=$i+1;
                        while((count($zeile) - 1 > $i) && (strtolower($key_regionprint) == strtolower($zeile[$k]->key_region)) && (count($zeile) - 1 > $k) && ($k > $i) && (strtolower($keyjahr) == strtolower($zeile[$k]->keyjahr))){
                            $anfang = htmlentities($zeile[$k]->beginn_f,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0);
                            $ende   = htmlentities($zeile[$k]->ende_f  ,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0);
                            $commen = ($zeile[$k]->comment_de) ? "<div class=\"comment\">". nl2br(htmlentities($zeile[$k]->comment_de,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0)) ."</div>" : "";
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'.$zeile[$k]->reisenr.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$zeile[$k]->keycountry.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$zeile[$k]->tourname.'</td>';
                            echo '<td class="commdate">'.$anfang.' &ndash; '.$ende.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.($zeile[$k]->tage+1).'&nbsp;T</td>';
                            if($zeile[$k]->price){
                                echo '<td>'.$zeile[$k]->price.'&nbsp;Euro</td>';
                            }
                            else{
                                echo '<td>-</td>';
                            }
                            echo '</tr>';

                            $j=$k+1;

                            while((count($zeile) - 1 > $i) && (strtolower($key_regionprint) == strtolower($zeile[$k]->key_region)) && (count($zeile) - 1 > $k) && ($k > $i) && (count($zeile) - 1 > $j) && ($j > $i) && ($keyjahr == $zeile[$k]->keyjahr) && ($jahr == $zeile[$j]->jahr) &&  (strtolower($key_region) == strtolower($zeile[$j]->key_region)) && (strtolower($keyregion) == strtolower($zeile[$i]->keyregion)) && (date("Y", strtotime($zeile[$i]->beginn)) == date("Y", strtotime($zeile[$j]->beginn))) ){

                                $anfang = htmlentities($zeile[$j]->beginn_f,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0);
                                $ende   = htmlentities($zeile[$j]->ende_f  ,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0);
                                $commen = ($zeile[$j]->comment_de) ? "<div class=\"comment\">". nl2br(htmlentities($zeile[$j]->comment_de,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8',0)) ."</div>" : "";
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo "<td>".$zeile[$j]->reisenr.'</td>';
                                echo "<td>".$zeile[$j]->keycountry.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$zeile[$j]->tourname.'</td>';
                                echo '<td class="commdate">'.$anfang.' &ndash; '.$ende.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.($zeile[$j]->tage+1).'&nbsp;T</td>';
                                if($zeile[$j]->price){
                                    echo '<td>'.$zeile[$j]->price.'&nbsp;Euro</td>';
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo '<td>-</td>';
                                }
                                echo '</tr>';
                                $i++;
                                $j++;
                            }
                            $k++;
                            $i++;
                        }
                    //     $i++;
                    //     $l++;
                    // }
                    $i++;
                    $newkeyjahrval = $keyjahr;
                    $newkey_regionprint = $key_regionprint;
                }

        ?>
```

CSS:

```
 table.termine {
    width: 180%;
    margin-bottom:0em;
    table-layout: fixed;

}
table.termine .reisenr {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -32px;
    right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

table.termine .land {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -32px;
    right: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

table.termine .date{

    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: -1.1em;
    position: relative;
    margin: -3px;
    left: 3px;

}

table.termine .datum {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    top: -32px;
    right: 260px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

table.termine .dauer {
    width: 7%;
    text-align: left;
    top: -32px;
    right: 260px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}



table.termine .preis {
    width: 7%;
    text-align: left;
    top: -10px;
    top: -32px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right:  430px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}
table.termine .reise {
    width: 19%;
    text-align: left;
    top: -32px;
    right: 230px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}


table.termine td .comment {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    max-width: none;
    width: 200%;
    margin-bottom: -2.5em;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
}
 .date{
    font-size: 22px !important;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
 .date1{
    font-size: 20px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}




td, th {
    padding: 10px;
}

table.termine tbody td:nth-child(1)    { text-align: left; position: relative; margin: 0px; top: -56px;    padding: 0px;}
table.termine tbody td:nth-child(2)    { text-align: left;    margin: 0px; top: -56px; position: relative;   padding: 0px; right: 130px;}
table.termine tbody td:nth-child(3)    { text-align: left; margin: 0px; top: -56px; position: relative;    padding: 0px; right: 220px;}
table.termine tbody td:nth-child(4)    { text-align: left; margin: 0px; top: -56px; position: relative;    padding: 5px; right: 255px;}
table.termine tbody td:nth-child(5)    { text-align: left; margin: 0px; top: -56px; position: relative;    padding: 0px; right: 250px;}
table.termine tbody td:nth-child(6)    { text-align: left; margin: 0px; top: -56px; position: relative;    padding: 0px; right: 420px;}


table.termine caption {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: -10px;
    left: 10px;
    top: -35px;
}

 #customers {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;

  }

  #customers td, #customers th {
    /* border: 1px solid #ddd; */
    padding: 8px;
  }
  table.termine tbody tr:hover {
    background-color:white;
}

  /* #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;} */

  /* #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;} */

  #customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    /* background-color:#fc453e; */
    color: white;
  }




  @media screen and (max-width:40em)    {
    table.termine    {    table-layout:auto;    }
    table.termine thead th:nth-child(1)    {    width:5.5em;    }
    table.termine thead tr th:nth-child(2)    {    width:auto;    }
    table.termine thead tr th:nth-child(3)    {    width:3.6em;    }
    table.termine tr :nth-child(4)    {    display:none;    }
    table.termine thead tr th:nth-child(5)    {    width:6.6em;    }
    table.termine thead tr th:nth-child(6)    {    width:6.6em;    }
    table.termine thead tr th:nth-child(7)    {    width:6.6em;    }
    table.termine tbody td .comment    {    max-width:100%;    width:auto;    }

}
@media screen and (max-width:38em)    {
    table.termine    {
        display:block;
        margin-bottom: -43px;
        padding: 0%;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    /* table.termine {
        width: 180%;
        margin-bottom:-1.3em;
        table-layout: fixed;

    } */
    table.termine thead    {
        display:none;
    }
    table.termine tbody    {
        display:block;
    }
    table.termine tr    {
        display:block;    width:100%;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:1ex;
        margin-bottom: -70px;
        top: -40px;
    }
    table.termine tbody td    {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(1)    {
        font-size: x-small;
        text-decoration: underline;
        top: 18px;
        position: relative;
        right: 8px;
        width: 102px;
    }
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(1):before    {
        content:"Reise Nr. ";
    }
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(2)    {
        display: block;
        line-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px;
        top: 15px;
        padding: 20px;
        right: 29px;
    }
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(3)    {
        display: block;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: inherit;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    right: 28px;
    height: 45%;
    width: 220px;
    top: -23px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(4)    {    display: block;
        display: block;
        line-height: 100%;
        text-align: inherit;
        position: relative;
        /* font-size: x-small; */
        margin: 0px;
        right: 14px;
        top: -101px;
    height: 45%;
    width: 230px;
}
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(5)    {
        font-size: x-small;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 200px;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        top: 0px;
    }
    table.termine tbody td:nth-child(6)    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 200px;
        top: 55px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    table.termine tbody td .comment    {
        font-style:italic;
        margin:0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 52px;
        width: 230px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    table.termine caption {
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: -1.1em;
        position: relative;
        margin: -24px;
        left: 15px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        top: -94px;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

        table.termine tbody td .social-links{
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative;
            top: 34px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        table.termine .reisenr {
            display: none;
        }

        table.termine .land {
            display: none;
        }

        table.termine .date{
            display: none;

        }

        table.termine .datum {
            display: none;
        }

        table.termine .dauer {
            display: none;
        }



        table.termine .preis {
            display: none;
        }
        table.termine .reise {
            display: none;
        }


        table.termine td .comment {
            display: none;
        }
        table.termine tr {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            /* margin-top: 9.8ex; */
            margin-bottom: -83px;
        }

        .date {
            font-size: 22px !important;
            position: relative;
            margin: 30px;
            top: -55px;
            right: 40px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }

        .date1 {
            text-align: left;
            margin-bottom: -1.1em;
            position: relative;
            margin: -24px;
            left: -79px;
            margin-top: 41px;
            top: -30px;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal example out of your code with dummy texts instead of PHP code?

Comment: @swatigoel, at first glance, you should make your table valid. The standard valid nesting of elements (`|` meaning "or") is `table->tbody|thead|tfoot->tr->td|th->anything`. You can also have a `<caption>` immediately under `<table>`. `<tbody>` is optional if alone. Stick to that and everything will work a lot better

Comment: See table doc here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table, `<tr>` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary

Comment: @julien.giband thank you it helps a lot